# How to replace all numbers, except specific numbers in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings, some of them are containing numbers.

for instance:

- abc123 def3464
- hello32 goodbye64
- some numbers 1254324

I want to clean up all numbers in those strings, but keep specific numbers, such as 32 and 64, so the clean up will return this:

- abc def
- hello32 goodbye64
- some numbers

Note, that in the first example (def3464) the number 64 exists, but not alone, therefore it should be eliminated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the task even without lambdas, relying solely on the
regex capabilities (although the regex is more complicated).

The regex needed is: `(?:(32|64)|\d+)(?=\D|$)`. Details:

- `(?:` - Start of the non-capturing group, needed as a container
  for alternatives.
- `(32|64)` - The first alternative (and capturing group), either
  `32` or `64`.
- `|` - Or.
- `\d+` - The second alternative, a sequence of digits.
- `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
- `(?=\D|$)` - The (common) ending part (after both alternatives) - positive
  lookup for either a non-digit char or end of string.

The first alternative (and capturing group) matches either `32` or `64`
and the second alternative (without capturing group) matches any other number.

The replacement expression is `\1` (replace the match with the content of
the first capturing group).

So, if the **second** alternative matched, the first group matched
**nothing**, hence nothing is put as the replacement for the current match.

To demonstrate how it works, run the example program:

```
import re
src = ['abc123 def3464', 'hello32 goodbye64', 'some numbers 1254324']
print(src)
result = [re.sub(r"(?:(32|64)|\d+)(?=\D|$)", r"\1", i) for i in src]
print(result)
```

If you are unhappy with the trailing space in the last output string,
add `.strip()` after `re.sub(...)`.

Comment: A parenthesis is missing from he example.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it (added the missing ")" after "\d+"). Thank you for perceptivity.

Comment: Thanks! works great - also on pandas:
df[string_column].str.replace(r"(?:(32|64)|\d+)(?=\D|$)", r"\1")

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = ['abc123 def3464', 'hello32 goodbye64', 'some numbers 1254324']
new_s = [re.sub('\d+', lambda x:['', x.group()][x.group() in ['32', '64']], i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['abc def', 'hello32 goodbye64', 'some numbers ']
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working but harder to implement when using pandas (it works but slowly - I forgot to mention that all of the data is in data frame).